# Cannot read property 'success' of undefined using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within my controller I do

```
topicContent.request().success(function(data){
        $scope.threadContent = data;
      });
```

and in my factory I wrote as below :

```
app.factory('topicContent', ['$http', function($http){
    return
            var query = function() {
                  $http({
                    url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
                    method: "GET"
                });
            }

            return {
                request : function(){
                    return query();
                }


            }
        }]);
```

I've checked there's no dependency error for my service. Any idea why it says success is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it.

```
var query = function() {
      return $http({
        url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
        method: "GET"
    });
}
```

Delete the return statement on line 2:

```
app.factory('topicContent', ['$http', function($http){
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning anything from `query()`. Try:

```
app.factory('topicContent', ['$http', function($http){

        var query = function() {
              // HERE!!
              return $http({
                url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
                method: "GET"
            });
        }

        return {
            request : function(){
                return query();
            }


        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Ok, throw up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following would can help helped:

In your Controller:

```js
topicContent.request().then(function(data){
    $scope.threadContent = data;
  });
```

And in the Service

```js
app.factory('topicContent', ['$http', function($http){

var query = function() {
    **return** $http({
        url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response){
        **return** response.data;
    });
}

return {
    request : query
    }

}]);
```

Note the 2 return statements in the query function of the service, and the simple returned object from the service.